# How to remove the elements from the list if the condition is true?

Tags: python, list

I two lists: one is the state list and the other one is the connections list:

```
connection = ['Rajasthan',12,'Punjab',234,'Haryana',333,'Himchal Pradesh', 320]
states = ['Delhi', 'Rajasthan']
```

I want to create a dictionary with each state name as the index and if that state name occurs in the `connection` list then that should be removed and also the number alongside with them, so if `Rajastjan` is occurring in the `connection` list then it should be removed and also the numbers which present alongside with it `12` So summary should look like this:

```
summary = {
    'State': Delhi,
    'Connection: ['Punjab',234,'Haryana',333,'Himchal Pradesh', 320],
}
summary ={
    'State': Rajasthan,
    'Connection: ['Punjab',234,'Haryana',333,'Himchal Pradesh', 320],
}
```

My approach for this is:

```
connection = ['Rajasthan',12,'Punjab',234,'Haryana',333,'Himchal Pradesh', 320]
states = ['Delhi', 'Rajasthan']

summary = {}
for i in range(len(states)):
    if states[i] in connection:
        connection.remove(states[i])
        summary = {
            'name': states[i],
            'connection': connection
        }
    if states[i+1] in connection:
        connection.remove(states[i+1])
        summary = {
            'name': states[i+1],
            'connection': connection
        }
print(summary)
```

and yes I know it is giving me the `outOfIndex` error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what about the condition? that if the state is present in the connection then remove it from the connection and then print it in the dictionary.

Comment: your `summary` dictionary is not valid since dictionary can only have unique keys but you have `State` and `connection` as keys multiple times.

Comment: Yeah I have updated the expected output

Comment: But really? We can't have multiple keys with the same name? I am just asking.

Comment: it is just how dictionary specification is defined, it is basically a key, value pair mapping. btw your expected object is still not clear, you can't have `summary` object to represent two dictionaries, may be you need a list of dictionaries.

Comment: and why does `Delhi` not have `Rajasthan` in the connection list? please formulate the problem description clearly

Comment: Becoz that's how it should be. I mean I can't include any of the items which are present in the state list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection = ['Rajasthan',12,'Punjab',234,'Haryana',333,'Himchal Pradesh', 320]
states = ['Delhi', 'Rajasthan']

def f(c, s):
    c = iter(c)
    for conn in c:
        if conn in s:
            next(c)
            continue
        yield conn

list(f(connection, states))
['Punjab', 234, 'Haryana', 333, 'Himchal Pradesh', 320]
```

This uses an [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) to loop over the `connection` list and to skip the number following a "match" (where the value is in the `states` list).

An iterator always implements a method `Iterator.__next__()` that can be called with next(Iterator), to get the next value.

So when there is a match `if conn in s`, we call `next(c)` to get the following number from `c` (that we don't care about). And then with `continue` the loop continues with the next state name.

If the value is not in `s`, it is `yield`ed. [Here is a great answer about  generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/5520354).

Comment: Hey, thanks, man this would work, I actually don't care if the result is in the list or dictionary.  But can you please a little bit why exactly this works?

Comment: I added some explanation. Feel free to ask if its still unclear.